# List, Carousel response by Api.ai not working on Actions Simulator

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, api-ai

In my app, one Intent returns *list* for Actions On Google which works fine on 'Test section' of Api.ai but fails to work on Actions Simulator.

> Test on Api.ai try: (worked fine)
>   [image: test on Api.ai]
>
> ---
>
> Test on Actions Simulator: (Fails)
>   [image: Test on Actions Simulator]
>
> ---

**NOTE: Other queries and intents are working fine on Actions Simulator for same app**

Do we need to use 'list' with some other message content?
The problem is same for Carousel Card also.
Earlier I got the same problem with basic card but fixed but by joining card with simple response but here that also didn't work.

Like 'basic_card' needs 'simple response' compulsorily, does 'list' also needs to be adjoined with something?

Please help to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed now!

Actually, There is **Problem with synchronization between Api.ai and ActionsOnGoogle**.

> So, to fix this issue we have to *disable Actions integration* and re-enable it 2-3 times.
>
> **And make sure:**
>
> *Additional triggering intents* are chosen properly.*
>
> *List or Carousel is having more than two items.* **(compulsorily)**

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem with list and carousel. When I select an item from list (or carousel) it doesn't find the matching intent. But when I repeat the same query (exact phrase), it finds it.

I've tried disabling/enabling Google Assistant integration.